# Page manager (or panels) override path

Tags: 8, panels

I want to override Drupal 8 paths (routes) like node/{node} or taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term} with custom panels variants. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page Manager module.  Add a new page that has the Path of `/taxonomy/term/%` and as @Todd Young wrote, disable the default Taxonomy view.

However, there is a bug that this is not working at https://www.drupal.org/node/2785195

[image: Taxonomy Term]

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Page Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/page_manager) module which you could use for this purpose.

> This is the Drupal 8 version of Page Manager, formerly part of the [CTools](https://drupal.org/project/ctools) module written by [merlinofchaos](https://drupal.org/user/26979)
>
> It supports the creation of new pages, and allows placing blocks within that page.
> Like Drupal 7's Page Manager, it provides a concept of "page variants", each with their own selection conditions.
> Additionally, it can be used to take over an existing page, like overriding /node/% to change what is displayed when viewing a node.

Comment: I'm already using it, but it works only for 'node/{node}'.  
I've tried to use several patterns: `/taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}`, `/taxonomy/term/%` - it doesn't works.  
Also I failed to override simple `/node` path.  
Which one should I use?

Comment: Downvote, because I'm asking for a practical solution, that one is theoretical only - it should work, but it doesn't. Perhaps I should create a bug report. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment but I don't have a reputation here yet.

The Page Manager module will indeed do what you are trying to accomplish.  The problem you are having in the comments is due to the path you are trying to use already being taken.

Drupal 8 comes with a stock View for the Taxonomy page.  You're probably setting the Page Manager page up correctly but you will need to disable this built-in View to "release" that path before it takes effect in your Page Manager page.